# Overlapped IO and ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, named-pipes

I have had overlapped IO working for 2 years now but ive used it with a new application and its chucking this error at me (when i hide the main form).

I have googled but i fail to understand what the error means and how i should handle it?

Any ideas?

Im using this over NamedPipes and the error happens after calling GetOverlappedResult

```
DWORD dwWait = WaitForMultipleObjects(getNumEvents(), m_hEventsArr, FALSE, 500);

//check result. Get correct data

BOOL fSuccess = GetOverlappedResult(data->hPipe, &data->oOverlap, &cbRet, FALSE);

// error happens here
```

Comment: Look, I know that overlapped I/O relates to I/O operations; Sockets, Disks etc'. You better tell us what kind of I/O you're doing and what is the EXACT error you're getting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE` is an error code that means that the Overlapped operation is still in progress; `GetOverlappedResult` returns false as the operation hasn't succeeded yet.

You have two options - blocking and non-blocking:

**Block until the operation completes:** change your `GetOverlappedResult` call to:

```
BOOL fSuccess = GetOverlappedResult(data->hPipe, &data->oOverlap, &cbRet, TRUE);
```

This ensures that the Overlapped operation has completed (i.e. succeeds or fails) before returning the result.

**Poll for completion:** if the operation is still in progress, you can return from the function, and perform other work while waiting for the result:

```
BOOL fSuccess = GetOverlappedResult(data->hPipe, &data->oOverlap, &cbRet, FALSE);
if (!fSuccess) {
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE) return; // operation still in progress

    /* handle error */
} else {
    /* handle success */
}
```

Generally, the second option is preferable to the first, as it does not cause your application to stop and wait for a result. (If the code is running on a separate thread, however, the first option may be preferable.)

Comment: I did try changing Wait to true. Just returned strait away.

Comment: In what part of your code is `data->oOverlap` set -- i.e. which function is first called using it?

Comment: Its set in the data constructor, the thing is that it works up until a point.

Comment: Found out what was killing it. Had an infinite loop which filled the pipe buffer causing data not to be able to be sent. What a strange error.